# Check condition from backend (if-else) without eval

Tags: javascript, node.js, eval

I have node script and backend, the script contains certain data and it got some conditions from backend.

For ex `node script`:

```
var data={
  count: 10,
  length: 27,
  days: 3
};
var condition = 'count > 10 && length < 3'; // <=== this condition got from backend
if( ... condition ...) {
  // action 1
} else {
  // action 2
}
```

Can I get condition result without `eval`? Because data from backend evals is unsafe for server. Or is there a way to run this condition in the sandbox?

Comment: what are the values the sting might have?

Comment: You have problem with architecture. You should send your condition not as string, but as object, something like this `[{field: 'count', operator: '>', value: '10'}, {field: 'length', operator: '>', value: '3'}]`

Comment: @degr I can do it, but how check every condition? and how check conditions like this `(a>3 && (b<3 || z> 6))`?

Comment: If you want to *not* blindly eval on any condition possible (+1 for that, by the way), at some point you will have to "describe" somewhere in your code what you can accept and handle. So you will have to define some kind of value / operator handling. the answer from Pieter-Jan below should be a good start, I guess.

Comment: (continued) : for the general case, without using predefined structured possibilities,  you will have to "parse" yourself an arbitrary condition. But this is a much more complicated problem, and you should look for external libraries that do this kind of job. Trying to code that from scratch won't be easy (nor safe) at first try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution is simple function with `runInNewContext`, condition runs in safe isolated sandbox with my variables

```js
var vm = require("vm");
function safeEval(code, variables = {}, opts) {
    var sandbox = Object.assign({
        _code_result_: undefined
    }, variables);
    vm.runInNewContext('_code_result_=(' + code + ')', sandbox, opts);
    return sandbox['_code_result_'];
}
var data = {
    count: 10,
    length: 27,
    days: 3
};
var condition = 'count >= 10 && length > 3'; // <=== this condition got from backend
if (safeEval(condition, data)) {
    // action 1
} else {
    // action 2
}
```

Comment: Thanks this was a great introduction to nodejs `vm` library

Answer (score 1):

Using some of the comments, something like this would probably help you?

```
var data = {    
  count: 11,    
  length: 27,    
  days: 3    
};    

var fromServer = [{field: 'count', operator: '>', value: '10'}, {field: 'length', operator: '>', value: '3'}];    

if (checkObjConditions(fromServer)) {    
  console.log("yes");    
} else {    
  console.log("no");    
}    

function checkObjConditions(co) {    
  //var conditions = c.split("&&");    
  var isCondition = true;    
  for (var a = 0; isCondition && a < co.length; a++) {    
    //var c = conditions[a].trim().split(",");    
    var r = compare(co[a]['field'], co[a]['operator'], co[a]['value']);    
    console.log(">", r);    
    if (!r)    
      isCondition = false;    
  }    
  return isCondition;    
}    

function compare(a, operator, b) {    
  var ans = false;    
  switch (operator) {    
    case '<':    
      if (data[a] < parseInt(b))    
        ans = true;    
      break;    
    case '>':    
    console.log(data[a], parseInt(b))    
      if (data[a] > parseInt(b))    
        ans = true;    
      break;
    // ... and other cases also    
  }    
  return ans;    
}
```